# How to get the primary route, if it doesn't exist and we are being sent to 404 page

Tags: codeigniter

So basically I am trying to debug my routes, because they are not working as intended, but when using the profiler, I can see the URI string, which is basically the second part of URL in the browser address bar and CLASS/METHOD which are always of the 404 page that I am being redirected to. So how can I get the primary routes Class, Method and arguments/parameters that were attempted to run before being sent to 404?

E.g.

```
$route['en/catalog/(.+)/(.+)'] = "ccatalog/index/$1/$2";
```

something's gone wrong and I get redirected to the 404, but I want to see which class (most likely "**ccatalog**" here), which method (hopefully "**index**") and arguments (**$1**, **$2**).

Thank you in advance to anyone who could help me with my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this was done really easy:

```
$this->uri->rsegment(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason for your route to not work.

Check by directly opening `your_path/ccatalog/index/whatever/whatever` in the browser.

If it gives you a 404, it means the problem is with your controller, maybe the controller or function naming.

If it is working fine, then you may be able to use a `pre_system` [hook](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html) to figure out the parameter values.

You may also consider hacking around with Routing files in the core(making sure you change them back), to figure out what the real issue is.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will look into hooking. The real issue was something I didn't ever consider - the order in which routes were written, just moved one route to the end and everything worked like a charm, but this question really was to know how to properly debug them in the future!